# Using link button in a gridview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a web app. In my app I have a gridview and a link button inside my gridview. My linkbutton looks like this:

```xml
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileData") %>' runat="server" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

In my table there is a link for every file, like(`~\userpic\chart.png`)

When user clicks on link button the following code should run

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "", "alert('No File to download.');", true);
        return;
    }
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

But when I run the code, I am unable to download the file. When I debug this method, debug breakpoint is not being hit. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check the 'Handle click event of linkbutton directly click event code' section of this link: [link](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/how-to-handle-click-event-of-linkbutton.html)

Comment: Post `GridView` code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your link button add a **CommandName** attribute

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileData") %>' runat="server" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" **CommandName="Download"**></asp:LinkButton>
```

and on your row command event

```
  protected void YourGridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        { 
           /*your code to download here */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are intended to display this `asp:LinkButton`  inside gridview rows, this `OnClick` event will not fire. You have to provide `OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"`
attribute for the gridview and write the code for `OnClick` inside the `GridView_RowCommand ()` method instead of `lnkDownload_Click()`. I hope this will work. Try it out.